# Why does the compiler not show an error when we try to divide a variable by zero

Tags: c#

If we try to run this code:

```
int d = 10/0;
```

We get a compiler error. So we cannot divide by zero.

Now consider this code:

```
  int d = 10;
  int o = d / 0;
```

**d can have anything and dividing anything by zero is not ok**

We don't get a compiler error. The variable has anything we cannot divide by zero. Why does the compiler not give an error when we try to divide a variable by zero?

Comment: Just look closely at the compiler error: "Division by **constant** zero".

Comment: Some newer compilers will actually do static analysis and tell you if you have a potential divide by zero on non-constant variables (both for r-hand and l-hand variables). Your compiler is just not one of the smarter ones, sadly.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Could you name any *newer* compiler which would report compile error/warning for that situation?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: I have seen it in Microsoft Visual C++ 2013, of course that was for the C++ compiler, with all warnings enabled. I don't know if they applied that to the C# compiler as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the C# Language Specification, chapter 7.18.  It talks about *constant expressions*.  I'll just summarize the basics.

The C# compiler makes an effort to try to evaluate an expression at compile time.  As long as the operands all have a known value and the operators are simple ones then the compiler can compute the value of the expression at compile time and use the result directly, instead of generating the code to evaluate the expression at runtime.  This sounds like an optimization, but it is not quite like that, constant expressions are *required* in a number of places.  Like the value of a **case** statement, declarations that use the **const** keyword, the values of an **enum** declaration and the arguments of an [attribute].

So no trouble with `10 / 0`, that's an expression with literal values and a simple operator so the compiler can directly compute the result and see that it will trigger an exception so complains about it at compile time.

The `d / 0` is *not* a constant expression because of the `d` variable.  You could argue that the compiler could well *know* the value of `d` since it got assigned in the statement above it.  But it doesn't do this, optimizing such code is the job of the jitter optimizer.

Answer (score 6):

Because your `d` variable is not constant.

Compiler does only basic (let say trivial) math checks. Your is not basic enough to be done by compiler, because it uses variable that is not `const`.

Comment: d can has anything and divide any thing with zero is not ok

Comment: You can have your custom `class`/`struct` with proper operator overriden which could be divided by `0`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - But the compiler knows that `d` is not a custom `class/struct` and is an `int`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek theoretically I agree, but in this case the result must cast to `int`, so the compiler checks the type of `d`, and thus knows it's an int or a type that can be automatically cast to int

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance, you have two constants, and so the compiler resolves this at compile time, thus finding the error.

In the second instance, as you have a non `const` variable(d), the compiler does not resolve this at compile time as it has no way of ensuring the value of `d` and thus will not spot the error. This will be evaluated at run time, where it will error out.

Answer (score 1):

The first:

```
int d=10/0;
```

will be resolved due compile time, because it is constant. The second will not be resolved because the compiler do only syntax checks, not math check.

Answer (score 0):

the c# compiler is only doing constants value arithmetic check, and there for can tell that you can't do `10/0`. it's a lot more then you think for a compiler to do that.

even more then that: the c# compiler allows:

```
1.0 / 0 // Infinity
```

because:

> Floating-point arithmetic overflow or division by zero never throws
>   an exception, because floating-point types are based on IEEE 754 and
>   so have provisions for representing infinity and NaN (Not a Number).