# Why does int i = 10; i / 0; compile, but 5 / 0 gives CS0020 - Division by constant zero?

Tags: c#

Consider the following snippet:

```
int i = 5 / 0;
```

This gives compiler error *CS0020: Division by constant zero*, which is fine.  However, the next snippet:

```
int i = 10;
i = i / 0;
```

Compiles just fine.

Does someone know why?  I see no reason why the compiler allows an integer variable to be divided by a zero integer constant.

Comment: I believe it is the difference between the compile time evaluation of the expression and the runtime one.

Comment: Isn't 5 / 0 a constant during compilation while i / 0 is not?

Comment: Two identical questions in a couple of minutes?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Yea, it too will probably get deleted before the homework has been turned in :D

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes we were discussing the issue outside Stack Overflow and decided to ask separately. My question is now deleted.

Comment: @CharlesMay Nick happens to be the one rating the homework and who gives this as a homework anyway?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18558119/6058174

Comment: @Matthiee now this is a great answer!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the general case, the compiler has no reason to disallow division by zero (or any other number) at runtime.

Your first example, though, is a *compile time* constant, i.e. it's calculated by the compiler and replaced with the result of the evaluation. This is what the compiler's complaining about as it rightly doesn't know what integer value to put in place of 5/0.

Comment: They could have made it so this case generates code to throw DBZ exception at runtime.

Comment: This doesn't hold for `anyInt / 0` : the compiler _could_ know it's always illegal.

Comment: @HenkHolterman in what case is it not true for anyInt / 0?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: given C#'s highly flexible rules for implicit conversions and operator overloading, I suspect the very specific case of someone writing down a literal `x / 0` expression with `x` an integral type didn't warrant a special check to issue a warning/error for that (and only that). It just leaves non-constant expressions to the runtime, always.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's not illegal by the specification of the language, as demonstrated by the fact that the program runs and throws an exception as expected.

Comment: @Stilgar In theory, yes, it could have been optimised to a throw statement, but I'd imagine that given the cost of throwing an exception vs the cost of an integral division, the compiler team have decided it's not worth the effort <insert EricLippert quote here>.

Comment: As a matter of fact I'd expect both cases to be a compile time error not an exception. Maybe too much work to justify the check though.

Comment: @Stilgar I think it's one of those "where would you draw the line?" cases. Checking for division of an integral type by a constant integral zero is simple enough, but then do you check for zero in a locally assigned variable? A parameter? Given how unlikely it is that a developer is going to put `x / 0` directly in their code (and that they'll find it when they run the program), it's not worth the effort. In the compile-time case, the check is mandatory because it's not compilable as-is.

Answer (score 7):

It is simply the difference between the compile time check and the runtime check. While

```
i = i / 0;
```

*throws*

> System.DivideByZeroException: 'Attempted to divide by zero.'

the

```
i = 5 / 0;
```

gives a compilation error

> Error  CS0020  Division by constant zero.

The value of `5 / 0` is evaluated at compile time, this is what makes the difference between receiving an error and getting an exception.

EDIT:

Given the comments to the answers here, I will take some time to write *an assumption* of why the compiler works this way:

The compiler was never intended to prevent division by zero of a variable. If you want to do it, you are allowed to, and you could work in some sneaky ways to get your program dividing by zero. What was the compiler supposed to do is just making some optimization when it can, by computing it advance some calculus and replace them with the resulting value. When it sees the division by zero, it just gives you an error as it can not compute it.

Comment: We know what it does, we are wondering why it was made this way.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the compiler converts `int i = 5 / 0;` to a constant value , so it must calculate the value during compile time, which gives it an error.

But the code

```
int i = 10;
i = i / 0;
```

is formally correct. It throws an exception and it is your decision and your intention to generate such an exception.

Comment: They could have made it so both throw exception or both give an error but they decided not to. The question is why they chose this specific and slightly inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

same as everyone saying here.
This line here is compile time and since compiler doesn't know the answer of this.It is giving error

```
int i = 5 / 0;
```

where as this line is a run time check and its just a general mathematical calculation so compiler  no reason to throw this as an error

```
 int i = 10;
 i = i / 0;
```